# UIAlertController is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I am trying to pop-up an alert when internet connection is not available, here's my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        print("Internet Connection Available!")
    }else{
        print("Internet Connection not Available!")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Pas de connection !", message: "Vous devez être connecté à Internet pour acceder à l'application", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "D'accord", style: .destructive, handler: {action in exit(-1)}))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }}
```

In the console, I have the print "Internet connection not available", but the alert is not showing, I tried to delete "self", but didn't work. I'm novice in swift, so if someone can help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you post more details? Are you in navigation controller stack?

Comment: Your code should have worked. Maybe there is something else interfering with the alert presentation which you've not added here.

Answer (score 0):

After I run your code, console prints the error below.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fc31700d000> on <SimpleExample.ViewController: 0x7fc31800c170> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Maybe this is your first view adding to the window, it cannot presents a view at this time.

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Pas de connection !", message: "Vous devez être connecté à Internet pour acceder à l'application", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "D'accord", style: .destructive, handler: {action in exit(-1)}))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```